# Meteor/MongoDB update all fields for entry

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

I'm using Mongo with Meteor and have wrote a basic CRUD, but wanted to know if it's possible to update all fields in an entry.  I can only seem to update a specific field in an entry, like this:

```
Brief.update(briefObject._id, { $set: { description: briefObject.description} });
```

Is it possible to update the entire entry by passing in the whole object?  I'm trying to keep my code dry and not have to write different functions to update different fields for an entry. Something like this:

```
Brief.update(brief._id, { $set: briefObject }
```

Here's an output of an example of an entry:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> schema = db.briefs.findOne();
{
    "_id" : "a56xpJ3ZTAzZKFmwD",
    "title" : "Foo",
    "client" : "Bar",
    "deadline" : ISODate("2017-01-01T12:00:00Z"),
    "description" : "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-15T16:20:46.403Z"),
    "username" : "fooBar"
}
```

Here's an example of `briefObject`:

```
{ title: 'Foo',
  client: 'Bar',
  deadline: Sun Jan 01 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  description: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet',
  createdAt: Fri Jan 15 2016 16:20:46 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  username: 'fooBar',
  _id: 'a56xpJ3ZTAzZKFmwD',
  '$$hashKey': 'object:4' 
}
```

Comment: In short, yes. But that also depends on your schema definition and if it matches with the properties in `briefObject`. Can you edit your question to show your `Brief` collection schema and a typical `briefObject` example?

Comment: yeah sure, i've updated the question.

Comment: You would need to delete the other two keys `_id` and `$$hashKey` before using the object in the update as these are reserved keys in Mongo.

Comment: How would you be able to look up the entry to update  if you've removed the `_id`?  Would a better option be to just reconstruct the whole object on update, something like this:
      `Briefs.update(brief._id, { $set:
        {
          title: brief.title,
          client: brief.client,
          deadline: brief.deadline,
          description: brief.description
        }
      });`

Comment: That's one way which works, but i've written a much better option which offers a much simper approach. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate the update object to use in the **`$set`** operator by removing the other two keys `_id` and `$$hashKey` before using it in the update. With this approach you don't have to recreate all the properties in the object, just delete the reserved keys from the new object and you're good to go.

You can create the selector and modifier objects that you can use in your **[`update`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-update)** as in the following example:

```
var selector = { "_id": briefObject._id },
    modifier = { "$set": briefObject };

delete modifier["$set"]["_id"];
delete modifier["$set"]["$$hashKey"];

Brief.update(selector, modifier);
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work pretty well.  I noticed that if you have any nested objects, you'll have to delete the `$$hashkey` for that as well.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams No worries :) In that case you would then have to loop through the nested objects and delete the fields as you mentioned.